# sprite kit make it run in 3.5 inch screen

Tags: uikit, sprite

I build the app for iphone, it is running well on the 4 inch screen, but whenever I try to run it on the3.5 inch thr bottom part gets cut off. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that it is a sprite kit game.the main.storyboard all set for the 4 inch retina and it is in portrait

Answer (score 1):

You must be manually setting sizes and locations.  Instead, if you dynamically set the locations and sizes based on size of the screen it should work.

BAD example:

Label.position = CGPointMake(100, 300);

GOOD example:

Label.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/3, self.size.height/3);

Answer (score 0):

Just set a playable area (to avoid the screen being truncated) and use

```
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when making my first simple Sprite Kit game. Work began on an iPhone 5S (4 inch screen), but when the game was loaded onto an iPhone 4S (3.5 inch screen) the screen was cut off. Here's the code, that I wrote inside my methods when needed, that fixed it for me:

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if (result.height == 480)
{
    NSLog(@"Old iPhone detected");
    //Write what ever code you need for the 3.5 inch screen here.
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"New iPhone detected");
    //Write what ever code you need for the 4 inch screen here.
}
```